# Can golang regex handle "binary" regular expressions similar to python?

Tags: python, go

Converting some python code to go, I need to match "binary" regexes, not containing valid utf8:

```
panic: regexp: Compile("^\xfd\xe2(..)(.)(..)\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00.+$"): 
error parsing regexp: invalid UTF-8: `��(..)(.)(..).+$`
```

Can this be done with the golang regexp library or what could be a similar alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to compile this regex you can use backticks ` instead of normal quotes.

```
regexp.Compile(`^\xfd\xe2(..)(.)(..)\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00.+$`)
```

In [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/a2Em4Hw8Wmk), somebody says

> You cannot get the regexp package to match a string that contains
> invalid UTF-8 sequences.

But it seems like when the escaping is done by the regexp package, not by the compiler, it works (which is why using backticks works but quotes don't). These escape sequences can also be found in the corresponding table on the [documentation page](https://pkg.go.dev/regexp/syntax?tab=doc#hdr-Syntax)

Comment: I have not tried this yet but imho the issue is not only on the side of the pattern but also on the side of the argument. The argument would be binary, too.

Answer (score 1):

Go `regexp` module cannot handle invalid UTF-8 at all. This is clearly stated in package overview: "All characters are UTF-8-encoded code points.".

Even if you include escapes like `\xfd\xe2` into your regular expression, it would actually match UTF-8 string `"\u00fd\u00e2"` (or `"\xc3\xbd\xc3\xa2"` as raw UTF-8 bytes).

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    r := regexp.MustCompile(`\xfd\xe2`)

    s1 := "\xfd\xe2"
    s2 := "\u00fd\u00e2"

    if s2 != "\xc3\xbd\xc3\xa2" {
        panic("")
    }

    fmt.Println(r.MatchString(s1)) // false
    fmt.Println(r.MatchString(s2)) // true
}
```

(Go Playground link: https://go.dev/play/p/HV62GExQ_5j)

If you look into `regexp` source code, you'll see that even if you call `Match(b []byte)`, in the end, it still works with runes decoded from UTF-8 byte strings. See `inputBytes.step` in [regexp/regexp.go](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17.6:src/regexp/regexp.go;l=430-439)